# Kernel Density Estimation in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark, kernel-density

I have recently become familiar with both PySpark's in-house KernelDensity function as well as sklearn's KernelDensity function.  I am trying to fit a Kernel Density Estimator to my data (some 14,000 data points, about 1.3 MB) so that I can draw more samples from the estimated distribution and generate a lot of synthetic data with similar statistical properties as my original data, (hopefully around 2-20 GB).  I know I can [do this in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_digits_kde_sampling.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neighbors-plot-digits-kde-sampling-py), but Spark's analogue doesn't seem to provide a similar method to draw samples from the resulting distribution.  Is there a way for me to build this functionality into Spark's KDE?  Are there any other tools I can use?  Or do I have to write this from scratch?  If so, please outline how to do that.

I know this seems like a lot of data to synthesize, but my research has to do with building a proof-of-concept for applying machine learning on big data for a particular problem domain, and we can't justify the use of a Spark cluster with only 1.3 MB.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity sklearn's KernelDensity function

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.stat.KernelDensity MLLib's KernelDensity function